# Bind service after ConfigureServices has completed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I'm running into an issue within my ConfigureServices method of Startup.cs where I need to GET (serviceProvider.GetService<>) a service I have bound, run a method (CreateEndpoint) from the bound service, return an object, and then bind that object as a singleton.

It seems if I run services.BuildServiceProvider() twice from within ConfigureServices, the app only seems to use the service provider from the first call, so the second call does not have my bounded singleton object included.

Alternatively, is there a way for me bind a service AFTER ConfigureServices has completed? The way I have it set up currently, the method CreateEndpoint fires off in the Configure method of Startup. The only problem with this is that I cannot actually bind the singleton object outside the ConfigureServices method.

Comment: Show a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the issue and also the desired behavior.

Comment: @NKosi I disagree that this question is off-topic. The desired behavior is very clear. It is answerable and has a very specific answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want something like this:

```
services.AddTransient<EndpointFactory>();
services.AddTransient(container => container.GetService<EndpointFactory>().CreateEndpoint());
```

you have to pass a function to your registration call if you need to resolve another service first.